# Searching array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to code the section of a game which will handle the collision detection. Currently it looks like this

```
def collision_detection(player_x, player_y):
movment_ok=1
cannot_go_onto=[[0,20,20,40],[520,500,480,460]] #coordinates with no access. X, Y
if player_x in cannot_go_onto[0]:
    location_in_array=cannot_go_onto[0].index(int(player_x))
    if player_y==cannot_go_onto[1][location_in_array]:
        print("collision detection")
        movment_ok=0
return movment_ok
```

This works fine for the coordinates `(0,520)`,`(20,500)` & `(40,460)` however it doesn't work for the coordinate `(20,480)`. I think this is because of the line

```
location_in_array=cannot_go_onto[0].index(int(player_x))
```

The index search is returning `1` because it simply takes the first time `20` appears in the array twice. Therefore only the position `(20,500)` is checked as it appears first in the array. However I don't know how to fix this problem. Any ideas/help would be hugely  appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler to just have an array of the no access coordinates, instead of 2 seperate lists.

```
cannot_go_onto = set([(0,520), (20,500), (20,480), (40,460)])

def collision_detection(player_x, player_y):
    play_position = (player_x, player_y)
    if play_position in cannot_go_onto:
        print("collision detection")
        return False
    return True
```

Edit:

- Placed cannot_go_onto outside the function because there is no need to recreate the array everytime.
- Made cannot_go_onto a set, which is better for searching performances. (Thanks tobias_k for pointing it out)

Comment: Might also make `cannot_go_onto` a `set`, and `global`.

Comment: Thank you for this, works perfectly now. Il accept your answer when the timer runs out.